# CPU governor settings

Tags: linux, cpu, power-management

What are CPU governor settings? How can I get their values, if they're set? I have 24 vCPUs on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

To get the current settings, run `cpufreq-info`.

For more information about cpu governors, you can e.g. look at the kernel documentation [Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt;h=c7a2eb8450c226b50e55b28f8c6669c6041cc0e3;hb=HEAD) or
look [here](http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling) or [here.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling)

For current processors, normally the `ondemand` governor gives the best power saving and good performance.